# Show only posts that need editing

Tags: support

I would like to help folks with first posts.

But all I see is "No action required."

Is there a setting to have it show only posts that need action?

https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1053682

Comment: There is a review queue for new posts. You can Edit there.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this meta question to include a link to the page where you only see "No Action Needed"? (I'm guessing you meant "No Action Needed" rather than "No action required." but either way please do edit in a link to where you're seeing that and only that.) If you can include a screenshot as well, that may be helpful. No review item should give you *only* that option. If that's happening, it's a bug. But if you're looking at a review *history* page, then it's possible there have just been many *recent* No Action Needed reviews. This wouldn't mean you couldn't take action, though.

Comment: I do not understand "take anything away" ? @pomsky

Comment: I meant what's your takeaway from Dan's answer to your previous question? (sorry for bad English) You asked the same question again and accepted a similar answer once again.

Comment: I was not aware I asked the same question twice. Dan's answer solved my problem for which I am grateful.  I do make mistakes. @pomsky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'No Action Needed' is a *decision* that you can make if there's nothing to do with a first post. Usually there is; you can upvote or downvote, add a comment, upvote and existing comment, (suggest an) edit or flag the question. Whenever you take one of these actions, the 'No Action Needed' will be disabled and the 'I'm Done' button will be enabled:

[image]